# Use XSLT to parse multiple attribute values and output them interleaved

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform something like this:

```
<IndexField NAME="Field1" VALUE="1;2;3" />
<IndexField NAME="Field2" VALUE="4;5;6" />
<IndexField NAME="Field3" VALUE="7;8;9" />
```

Into something like this:

```
<Document>
    <Field1>1</Field1>
    <Field2>4</Field2>
    <Field3>7</Field3>
</Document>
<Document>
    <Field1>2</Field1>
    <Field2>5</Field2>
    <Field3>8</Field3>
</Document>
<Document>
    <Field1>3</Field1>
    <Field2>6</Field2>
    <Field3>9</Field3>
</Document>
```

This post ([Using XSLT 2.0 to parse the values of multiple attributes into an array-like structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339114/using-xslt-2-0-to-parse-the-values-of-multiple-attributes-into-an-array-like-str)) was helpful, but doesn't quite get me all the way there, as interleaving the output makes this much more complex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9? Or if you are restricted to XSLT 1.0 which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0, with the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:variable name="IndexFields" select="IndexField"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Fields">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$IndexFields"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$Fields/*" group-by="(position() - 1) mod count($IndexFields)">
    <Document>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="IndexField">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@VALUE, ';')">
    <xsl:element name="{$this/@NAME}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the input sample

```
<Root>
<IndexField NAME="Field1" VALUE="1;2;3" />
<IndexField NAME="Field2" VALUE="4;5;6" />
<IndexField NAME="Field3" VALUE="7;8;9" />
</Root>
```

is transformed into

```
<Document>
   <Field1>1</Field1>
   <Field2>4</Field2>
   <Field3>7</Field3>
</Document>
<Document>
   <Field1>2</Field1>
   <Field2>5</Field2>
   <Field3>8</Field3>
</Document>
<Document>
   <Field1>3</Field1>
   <Field2>6</Field2>
   <Field3>9</Field3>
</Document>
```